# What is the best approach to retrieve records from one table that stores it's history?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relational-database

I have one dummy table 'Users', let's call it U, and another table 'DataFromUsers', DU. From time to time i'll save a new record into DU, related to one U, and now we have 2 records pointing to the same user U. It'll come the time when i'll have lots of entries in DU resembling to this condition.

The best approach i can see to solve this problem is always storing it's insertion date, once all i care is the most recent DU from U, and am only keeping the old entries for analytical purposes.

Another way would be having a FK in U pointing straight to the most recent record from DU, but that would create a need to always update two tables, and i don't know whether this is a good idea or not (in matters of maintainability and performance).

Comment: Absolutely do NOT add a foreign key to your parent table that indicates which child row it should use. That is a very bad design idea. I would include a DateCreated or whatever name. It might also make sense to take any existing data in DU and move it to an archive/history table so you don't have to beat yourself up over which row to use.

Comment: In the Child Table, depend on an Identity Column to get the most recent record.  By the way, i saw both solution, the adding reference key in the parent table (even logically) cause a lot of problem because most of developer will not expect this desing. the most appropriate solution (for readability and maintenance) is to get the child record with the highest Identity_Value.

Comment: From time to time you'll save a new record? You mean at random times throughout the day you'll select a record also at random and write a copy to the DU table? Surely not! So what does the data in the DU table represent and when do you insert new rows to it? It sounds like you just need to version your data...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general case, you would include an integer version field in the child table.<sup>1</sup>

But in the specific case of SQL Server, including the explicit foreign key in the parent table would allow you to create an [indexed view](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/what-you-can-and-cant-do-with-indexed-views/) and effectively cache JOIN between the parent and most recent child. Consider carefully whether you actually need that, and if you do, be very careful not to let this FK go out of sync!<sup>2</sup>

---

*<sup>1</sup> Date/time can be problematic if your database server's clock ever goes out of sync, but you can include it (just) for informative purposes in addition to the integer version.*

*<sup>2</sup> You'd have to lock the parent before inserting new child, to avoid race conditions in concurrent environment **and** you'd have to make sure all clients follow that. Fortunately, the mere attempt to UPDATE the parent row (to set the new FK value) also locks it.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. Instead of using a version field, using the identity column on a surrogate ID field to retrieve the biggest one related to one specific parent is any better (as suggested in the the question post)? The date/time field would be (i'm not even sure it will, but i'm saving this information just in case) used to perform a progress analysis.

Comment: @v1n1akabozo Identity field is also integer :) It doesn't really matter how you'll manage the version field (manually or just let the DBMS generate it for you), as long as it is ordered properly...